# Eliminate sub queries from this Query

Tags: sql, join

I have these tables

**User**

```
User_Id int PK, User_Name varchar(50)
```

**Page**

```
Page_Id int PK, Page_Name varchar(50)
```

**Permission**

```
Permission_Id int PK , User_Id int FK, Page_Id int FK, 
Read bit, Write bit, Delete bit
```

**Requirements:**

1. Query to select all from `Page` plus `Read, Write, Delete` from `Permission` of that page according to provided `@User_Id`.
2. If `@User_Id` isn't passed all Pages should be selected with `null` in `Read, Write, Delete`.
3. If provided `@User_Id` doesn't exists in `Permission` then `Read, Write, Delete` should be selected as `null`.
4. There may be some case when `permission` would have records for some but not all `pages` associated with a `user`, In that case all records of `pages` should come up and for those pages which doesn't have associated `user_id` there should be `null` in `Read, Write, Delete` columns.

**What I have done is this**

```
declare @User_Id int=null; 

    SELECT 
     page.Page_Name,
     page.Page_Id,
     isnull((select Read from Permission where
         (@User_Id is null OR User_Id = @User_Id ) and 
         (Permission.Page_Id = Page.Page_Id)),0)
         as Read,
     isnull((select Write from Permission where 
         (@User_Id is null OR User_Id = @User_Id) and 
         (Permission.Page_Id = Page.Page_Id)),0) 
         as Write,
     isnull((select Delete from Permission where 
         (@User_Id is null OR User_Id = @User_Id) and 
         (Permission.Page_Id = Page.Page_Id)),0) 
         as Delete,
     isnull((select Export from Permission where 
         (@User_Id is null OR User_Id = @User_Id) and 
         (Permission.Page_Id = Page.Page_Id)), 0) 
         as Export  
    FROM Page
```

This query works fine and fulfill all requirements but as you can see it has `sub queries` which I want to eliminate, one option could be `sql functions` but I want to know if there's some other way to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

declare @User_Id int=null;

```
SELECT 
    page.Page_Name,
    page.Page_Id,
    ISNULL(Read,0) AS Read
    ISNULL(Write,0) AS Write,
    ISNULL(Delete,0) AS Delete,
    ISNULL(Export,0) AS Export
FROM 
    Page
    LEFT JOIN Permission ON Page.Page_ID = Permission.Page_ID AND Permission.User_ID = @User_ID
```

If you join on the @userID parameter too then when it is null it will not match with any of the rows in Permissions, and therefore your values will be NULL

Comment: `Page.User_ID` ?? page doesn't have `User_ID`.

Comment: Sorry typo, i meant permission.user_id. Edited

Comment: It worked actually I had placed `Permission.User_ID = @User_ID` in where clause I guess because of that it didn't worked, Can you explain why it didn't worked in where clause.

Comment: If you put it in WHERE clause then every page record would have joined with every permission record for that page (presumably for the wrong users). If you put it in the JOIN clause you ensure that you only get the permissions relating to both the page and user. By using a LEFT join, you get every page, even if there are no permissions for the userID. If there are no permissions for the userID then the Read, Write etc will return null. If you used an INNER JOIN then the Page records would not be in the results as the join clause would have failed. That OK?